# How to add force to non connected objects in d3.js in javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to add force to non connected objects in d3.js?

Following is demo of a force directed graph in d3.js

https://jsbin.com/bijoxozuno/edit?html,css,js,output

This is the force code:

```
    force.on("tick", function() {
      dataset.nodes.forEach((node, i) => {
        const circle = layer.findOne(".node-" + i);
        circle.x(node.x);
        circle.y(node.y);
      });
      dataset.edges.forEach((edge, i) => {
        const { target, source } = edge;
        const line = layer.findOne(".edge-" + i);
        line.points([target.x, target.y, source.x, source.y]);
      });
      layer.draw();
    });
```

Imagine if I have some other entities like a separate square or a circle which when collides with the force connected graph; it should interact (like attract or repel).

How can I achieve that?

Cause currently all the connected nodes are interacting well(attracting and repelling).
But my need is to extend this interaction further with other third party objects (like a different circle or square) which is not connected to the graph. but is under the influence of same force.

**NOTE** What I want to achieve is simply I want the connected nodes to interact with objects that are not part of the connected graph... but is under the influence of the same force.

**Example the red rectangle in the above example**